# React - stuck passing promise as prop. How to avoid inifintely re-drawing component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Due to some design error of a library I'm using I'm stuck using a Promise instead of using the data directly - something like this:

```
import { ICellRendererParams } from 'ag-grid-community';
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { useState } from 'react';

export interface JudeteCellRendererParams extends ICellRendererParams {
    judetePromise: Promise<AxiosResponse<any, any>>;
}

function SelectJudetCellRenderer(props: JudeteCellRendererParams) {
    let [judete, setJudete] = useState([{id: 'test', nume: 'test'}]);
    props.judetePromise.then((response: any) => {
        setJudete(response.data)     
    });
    return (
        <select name="judete">
        {
            judete.map((judet, index) => 
            {
                return <option key={index} value={judet.id}>{judet.nume}</option>;
            })
        }
      </select>
    )
}

export default SelectJudetCellRenderer;
```

but now my component is stuck in an infinite re-drawing loop because the component gets re-rendered (from using the useState hook in the then block).

Is there any way to avoid this while having the data from the response set to the 'judete' variable?

Thanks.

Comment: Just wrap the `then` in a `useEffect` with the promise as a dependency.

Comment: FYI: I think the error here is actually in **your** design. It's in the fact that you pass the promise instead of waiting for the promise and then passing the value.

Comment: @super unfortunately, no. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73088973/react-ag-grid-how-to-refresh-the-value-of-a-cellrendererparam

Comment: @super it worked this way. Can you add that as an answer? I'll accept it asap

Comment: Frankly, investing time to going through a code example like that is hardly worth the effort. I did have a look at it, but it's not complete. So who knows what it's actually doing. Let's just say I bet all my marbles on the fact that you are wrong, and it can be solved with a much cleaner design without needing to pass a promise.